# Multiline script in conditional break

Tags: windbg

I'm using windbg like the following:

```
bp XXX!XXXX::Init ".printf \"init tid=%d, XXX=0x%x\", @@c++(@$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread), @rdx; .echo; g;"
```

Is there a way to avoid the `\"` and the one-liner here? I'm trying to be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

1. avoid .printf as much as you can it has certain limitation on format string length
2. resume from conditional breakpoint with gc (go from conditional ) instead of g (go)as you do
   one alternate way to accomplish what you are doing could be like

   0:000> bp **00007ff8`854ec941** "dx @$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread;r @rdx;gc"

   0:000> pc

   @$teb->ClientId.UniqueThread : 0x23cc [Type: void *]

   rdx=0000020996d22868

   **00007ff8`854ec941** call fastprox!CWbemSvcWrapper::XWbemServices::WrapBSTR